# Remove only top and bottom margins using pdfcrop

Tags: pdfcrop

I usually use `pdfcrop` to remove white margins of pdf illustrations in `LaTeX` documents. Using it by command line:

```
pdfcrop myfigure.pdf
```

it removes all margins but to avoid  me to resize the figure (if it has left and right white margins) I need a way to remove only top and bottom margins. I mean someting like

```
pdfcrop --margins '- 0 - 0' input.pdf
```

(where the `-` should be a way to make pdf crop keep the original margin) to set top and bottom margins to `0` keeping original left and right margins.

Perhaps, if there is a tool to measure the white margins of a (single page) `.pdf` file, I could write a script to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pdfcrop` reports the bounding boxes if option `--verbose` is given, e.g.:

```
pdfcrop --verbose test.pdf
```

It reports:

```
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
[...]
* Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
[...]
Page 1
%%BoundingBox: 133 89 308 668
* Page 1: 133 89 308 668
%%HiResBoundingBox: 133.767980 89.369997 307.295991 667.205980
[...]
```

In this case, the left margin is 133. The right margin can be calculated via the width. The size of the PDF file is reported by `pdfinfo` (assuming the pages have all the same size), e.g.:

```
pdfinfo test.pdf
```

It reports:

```
[...]
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
[...]
```

Then the missing values for `--margins` can be calculated and added:

```
pdfcrop --margins '133 0 288.276 0' test.pdf
```

Alternatively the bounding box option can be used:

```
pdfcrop --bbox '0 89 595.276 668' test.pdf
```

Comment: This helps a lot. Please consider to add this feature to your software. I mean a way to crop to `0` only the desidered margins, keeping the other unchanged.

Comment: I found that your solution does't work for the right margin. Indeed it doesn't keep the original margin but adds more white space to it.

Comment: You need to get the figure's width, e.g. with `identify figure.pdf`, and then subtract the right bounding box value to get the right margin value.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Thanks, answer fixed and a variant with option `--bbox` added.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has a script that can do this in one fell swoop?

Comment: I'm also in the need for keeping the width of my PDF but trim the vertical whitespace. I have generated a PDF from libreoffice draw with the correct width. Configuring the correct height, however, is more difficult for me. (And yes, I think that this is a bug in that software, but here we go.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a scripted version I created. Thought this might be of use for other people.

```
#!/bin/bash
fname="$1"
pagesize=( $(pdfinfo "$fname" | grep "Page size" | cut -d ":" -f2 | \
    awk '{ print $1,$3 }') )
bounding=( $(pdfcrop --verbose "$fname" | grep "%%HiResBoundingBox" | \
    cut -d":" -f2 ) )
rm "${fname//.pdf/-crop.pdf}"
lmarg="${bounding[0]}"
rmarg="$(python -c "print(${pagesize[0]} - ${bounding[2]})")"
pdfcrop --margins "$lmarg 0 $rmarg 0" "$fname" "$fname"
```

Comment: Neat. I had to change the print to `print('{:.3f}'.format(${pagesize[0]} - ${bounding[2]}))`, otherwise python used scientific notations for small margins and pdfcrop couldn't parse that